How to feed frames one by one and grab decoded frames using LibAV?
I am integrating a third party system where I send a TCP packet to ask e.g. 5 frames from a live CCTV camera stream, and it sends those 5 frames one by one. Each package is h264 encoded frame, wrapped with some relevant data.
I need to write a code using Libav where I can:

Feed the frames one by one using AVIOContext (or smth similar).
Grab decoded frame.
Draw that to a window (Not relevant to the question, writing for context).

I've been doing the same with GStreamer by creating a pipeline like this:
AppSrc -> H264Parser -> H264Decoder -> FrameGrabber

The code below is what I was able to write so far:
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using FFmpeg.AutoGen;

namespace AvIoCtxExperiment;

public static unsafe class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ffmpeg.avdevice_register_all();
        Console.WriteLine($"FFmpeg v: {ffmpeg.av_version_info()}");

        // Generous buffer size for I frames (~43KB)
        const int bufferSize = 50 * 1024;

        var buff = (byte*)ffmpeg.av_malloc(bufferSize);
        if (buff == null)
            throw new Exception("Buffer is null");

        // A mock frame provider. Frames are stored in separate files and this reads & returns them one-by-one.
        var frameProvider = new FrameProvider(@"D:\Frames-1", 700);
        var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(frameProvider);

        var avioCtx = ffmpeg.avio_alloc_context(
            buffer: buff,
            buffer_size: bufferSize,
            write_flag: 0,
            opaque: (void*)GCHandle.ToIntPtr(gch),
            read_packet: new avio_alloc_context_read_packet(ReadFunc),
            write_packet: null,
            seek: null);

        var formatContext = ffmpeg.avformat_alloc_context();
        formatContext->pb = avioCtx;
        formatContext->flags |= ffmpeg.AVFMT_FLAG_CUSTOM_IO;

        var openResult = ffmpeg.avformat_open_input(&formatContext, null, null, null);
        if (openResult < 0)
            throw new Exception("Open Input Failed");

        if (ffmpeg.avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, null) < 0)
            throw new Exception("Find StreamInfo Failed");

        AVPacket packet;
        while (ffmpeg.av_read_frame(formatContext, &packet) >= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"GRAB: {packet.buf->size}");
            ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(&packet);
        }
    }

    private static int ReadFunc(void* opaque, byte* buf, int bufSize)
    {
        var frameProvider = (FrameProvider?)GCHandle.FromIntPtr((IntPtr)opaque).Target;
        if (frameProvider == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        byte[] managedBuffer = new byte[bufSize];

        var fBuff = frameProvider.NextFrame();
        if (fBuff == null)
        {
            return ffmpeg.AVERROR_EOF;
        }

        int bytesRead = fBuff.Length;
        fBuff.CopyTo(managedBuffer, 0);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            Marshal.Copy(managedBuffer, 0, (IntPtr)buf, bytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine($"READ size: {fBuff.Length}");
            return bytesRead;
        }

        return ffmpeg.AVERROR_EOF;
    }
}

Second thing that confuses me is with AppSrc, I can feed frame of any size, but with LibAV, it asks for buffer size. With AppSrc, I am responsible of feeding frames into the pipeline. GStreamer notifies me when it is enough with signals. But with libav, it calls read_packet delegate itself.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.
P.S. I'm writing a C# app, but sample code in C is fine, I can adapt the code myself.

I'm not sure if this is on-topic for Super User, or should be migrated to Stack Overflow. The question seems to be about creating a program which uses LibAV and the Super User What topics can I ask about here? contains "and it is not about programming and software development".

Yes I figured this out too. Just posted a question at SO, was going to delete this one.

This question is similar to: How to feed frames one by one and grab decoded frames using LibAV?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
